# How to deal with recursive function contains observable?

Tags: angular, observable

My model has a "name" property,I should check if any model instance already has this name first when i save this property,if there is,i'll regenerate a name and repeat the above.The problem is i have no idea how deal with such situation with Observable.I tried recursive function, but it doesn't work!
Could anyone give me some help?

```
test(name: string): string {
    const url = `/api/products/?name=${name}`;
    return this.http.get<any>(url).map(data => {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        name = "an other name";
        this.test(name);
      }
      return name;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Try putting your call to this.test(name) inside of a .subscribe instead of inside the .map(). If this test(name: string) function must return an observable, then in your subscribe you can return Observable.of(name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three changes needed:

1. Try using `concatMap` instead of using map.
2. Change `return name;` to `return return Observable.of(name)`.
3. Don't forget to return the recursive `this.test(name)`

---

```
test(name: string): Observable<string> {
    const url = `/api/products/?name=${name}`;
    return this.http.get<any>(url).concatMap(data => {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        name = "an other name";
        return this.test(name);
      }
      return Observable.of(name);
    });
  }
```